# Why is this assignment operator not working?

Tags: c++, oop, variable-assignment, stdvector, assignment-operator

I have a vector `SolventInGrid` of objects `Particle`. `SolventInGrid` is an attribute of the object `NewGrid`.
The object `Particle` has 3 attributes: `coords` which is a `vector <int>`, `ptype` which is a cpp string, and `orientation` which is an `int`.

What I want to do is, I want to find a Solvent particle in `SolventInGrid` with certain coordinates `to_rot` and replace them with `loc_0`. I have a function which does some other things, and at the end of the day, makes this change. It works if I do this:

```
...
        for...
            // update position of the solvent particle you displaced during this move 
            int c =0; 
            for (Particle P: NewG.SolventInGrid){
                c++; 
                if (P.coords == to_rot){ 
                     
                    break;
                }

            }
            NewG.SolventInGrid.at(c-1).coords = loc_0; 
            break;
            

        }


    }

    return NewG;
}
```

However, if I do:

```
...
        for ...

            // update position of the solvent particle you displaced during this move 
            int c =0; 
            for (Particle P: NewG.SolventInGrid){
                if (P.coords == to_rot){ 
                    P.coords = loc_0; // this is the assignment statement to the Particle P within NewG.SolventInGrid
                    break;
                }

            }
            
            break;

        }


    }

    return NewG;
}
```

and if I print out the contents of NewG.SolventsInGrid, there is no change in the contents of the vector. There is no element with loc_0 as the coordinates. (There is none to begin with.)

What could be the cause of this? Why is such assignment bad/incorrect?

Comment: `for(Particle P: NewG.SolventInGrid)` `P` is a copy of an element in `NewG.SolventInGrid`. If you want a reference, that's `for(Particle& P: ...)`

Comment: Huh. So, when I am iterating through vectors using the for (...: ...) form, it is always a copy?

Comment: Yes it will be copies : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: If you want to iterate references (instead of copies), use `for (Particle& P : ...)` with the ampersand.